# Compositions and Restricted Domains

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[image]

Hey guys. I got the answer under question 3 (which is circled). Can you please verify if it is correct? If not, can you please specify how to go about this problem? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? :)

Comment: Is my answer for number 3 correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have that

$$f(x)=x+2,-11\le x\le17\\
g(x)=2x-1,x\le2$$

then

$$f[g(x)]=(2x-1)+2=2x-1+2=2x+1,-11\le g(x)\le17$$

wich gives

$$-11\le2x-1\le17\\
-10\le2x\le18\\
-5\le x\le9$$

but from $g(x)$ we have that $x\le2$, then we gets that

$$-5\le x\le9\wedge x\le 2=\\-5\le x\le 2$$

wich is your answer, then its correct.

Comment: Thanks Cand!A detailed explanation!